# Node.js execute shell command which requires an input after a few seconds

Tags: node.js, bash, vercel

I'm trying to use the now cli to purchase a domain through my Node.js server but I cannot figure out how to execute a shell command in Node and to automatically insert the input when asked.

Here's my command using `child_process.exec`

```js
const { stdout } = await exec(`now --token ${NOW_TOKEN} domains buy ${domainName}.${tld}`)
```

This does nothing because the command is waiting input `(y/N)` to confirm buying the domain.
They don't have any option in the commande to bypass the question like `--yes`.

How can I pass a string `y` + `Enter` when the process is waiting ?

Comment: They have an api that can be used - https://zeit.co/docs/api#endpoints/domains/purchase-a-domain - you can use the request module to call it, no need for exec.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of this API and this seems like the best option for my project.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful. Your usage can certainly violate their [ToS](https://zeit.co/terms) if you are reselling parts of their offering. You may need to reach out to their [support channel](https://zeit.co/support) for clarification.

Regarding the code. You can take a look at this file for inspiration: https://github.com/zeit/now/blob/master/packages/now-cli/test/integration.js

One alternative is:

```
stdin.write('y\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm pretty sure I'm not violating their ToS since I'm creating a SaaS product where every customer instance is hosted on Zeit. All I want is to allow customers to buy a domain and link it to their product instance.  Using the CLI was the best way because it's easier to then link the domain to a deployment.

Regarding the command you gave me, it works but I also found an alternative solution : `yes | now --token ${NOW_TOKEN} domains buy ${domainName}.${tld}`